# Set UITableView's superview height accordingly to the number of table view cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

My UITableView is embedded within a `UIView`, I would like that this superview's height change according to the number of `UITableViewCell`s the table view has.

That mean, if the tableView has 1 cell, `UIView` will be the size of this cell, if there are 2 cells, the `UIView` will grow to the size of 2 cells.

Answer (score 1):

I would add one more `UIView` to `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView` which I would use as content view. Then I would set `backgroundColor` of real `contentView`

[image]

Comment: @AamirR I understand that question like this: He has `UITableView` with fix height and he needs to change color behind visible cells. So if there would be just one cell, just behind this cell would be colored background. If there would be two cells, just behind these two cells would be colored background.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Autolayout constraints, you can just update UITableView's height constraint itself and that should do the job.

Here are the basic steps:

1. Subclass UITableView:

   ```
   class CustomTableView: UITableView {

       var maximumTableViewHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

       private var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

       override func reloadData() {
          super.reloadData()
           self.heightConstraint.constant = min(self.contentSize.height, maximumTableViewHeight)
       }

       override func awakeFromNib() {
           super.awakeFromNib()

           self.heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil,
                                                      attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
           self.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
       }

   }
   ```
2. Storyboard that has our subclassed `CustomTableView`

[image: Storyboard]

3. Then your view controller:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

       @IBOutlet var tableView: CustomTableView!
       private let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

       var dataSource: [Int] = [1, 2, 3] {
           didSet {
               self.tableView.reloadData()
           }
       }

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           self.tableView.dataSource = self
           self.tableView.maximumTableViewHeight = 400 // Adjust as per your max height
       }

       @IBAction func addCell(_ sender: Any) {
           let count = self.dataSource.count + 1
           self.dataSource.append(count)

           let scrollToIndexPath = IndexPath(row: count - 1, section: 0)
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: scrollToIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
           }
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return self.dataSource.count
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
           if cell == nil {
               cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
           }

           cell.textLabel?.text = "Value: " + String(dataSource[indexPath.row])
           return cell
       }

   }
   ```

That yields:

[image]

Notice the **red** area, thats the parent `UIView` of `UITableView`

Comment: See sample project at https://github.com/r-aamir/AutolayoutHeightTableView